# Is a JSON serialization deserialization library of any use

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, serialization

It just strikes me that What can `JSON.net` library do in special that a `JavaScriptSerializer` class does not?

1. Is it worth including in a large enterprise application that talks through SOAP webservices and javascript?
2. What performance gain/ development gain i get by including such libraries in the project?
3. Are there similar libraries that aid in object serialization/ deserialization faster, better and smarter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685429/serializing-data-using-json-net-size-limit/7685498#7685498

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647651/c-datacontractjsonserializer-fails-when-value-can-be-an-array-or-a-single-item/7648147#7648147

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626717/how-to-parse-json-to-a-dynamic-object-on-windows-phone-7/7626755#7626755

Comment: @L.B as for the size limit we keep it short and efficient so no probs, as for second link does make sense, We would not do the same for the phone. The application would be developed by different team. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes it is. Absolutely. Just because something comes by default with the .NET framework built by Microsoft it does not mean that it's the best thing to use. The size of an application, nor where it's deployed, in my view is hardly a determining factor of whether a library like JSON.net should be used. Look at your own needs and use that as the driver, not the size of your app.
2. Substantial. JSON.net is really fast, has a lot more features and is a much "friendlier" API to use. I wouldn't hesitate recommending it for use in any application. I have personally used it in Enterprise applications, open source libraries and WP7 games.
3. There are lots of similar libraries. [JsonFx](http://jsonfx.net/) is one. Is it faster, better and smarter? Yes and no, yes and no, and yes and no respectively. There is no golden bullet for this kind of thing. You should investigate your needs and figure out which one suits you. I can almost guarantee that if you're happy to use the out-of-the-box JavascriptSerializer you won't (can't!) be disappointed with the features and speed of either of these other options.

HTH.

Comment: do you have any references for comparison b/w builtin serializer and that of JSON.net

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much details about the libraries. One thing I needed to do was serializing the Enums.If I use default serializer it will serialize the value of the enum ,but I wanted to get the name.
So I did this using `Newtonsoft.Json` (`JSON.net`)like this,

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public  SearchResultType SearchResultType { get; set; }
```

Comment: not much of a buying point, because my application would have equivalent enums on client script. Which would convert back to names. Also my objects would be strongly typed strings and arrays so does not convince me. `But yes Microsoft missed Enum serialization from their list wtf`