# SimpleJson in WP8

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I am trying to parse a json file in WP8. For the moment I just need to get a list of topics with some titles each one. Something like:

```
[
{"topic":"topic1", 
 "titles":[{"title":"tit1"},
           {"title":"tit2"},
           {"title":"tit3"}]},
{"topic":"topic1",
 "titles":[{"title":"tit1"},
           {"title":"tit2"},
           {"title":"tit3"}]}
]
```

My idea is get each topic and save in an array of 2 dimensions. In topic[X][0] would go topic and topic[x][y] the titles...

I have found this topic: [Deserializing JSON using JSon.NET with dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738031/deserializing-json-using-json-net-with-dynamic-data)

In which is explained a bit how to do it but I am not able to get any of my data because the structure of the json is not similar. Any idea of how to do in this case?

Comment: You just need `List` of your objects `topic` in which would be `List` of `Title`s. And then you can parse using JSon.NET your json to your object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse just call:

```
JArray json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText) as JArray;
```

For getting the topics just access it normally:

```
JObject arrayItem = json[0] as JObject;
```

Getting the topic and it's value:

```
JValue topic = arrayItem["topic"] as JValue;
string topicValue = topic.Value.ToString();
```

Getting the titles:

```
JArray titles = ArrayItem["titles"] as JArray;
```

And getting their values:

```
foreach (JObject jo in titles)
{
    JValue title = jo["title"] as JValue;
    string titleValue = title.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: you can go here: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html however I learnt it by assigning the values to a var and reading the debug information.