# How to deserialize HttpContent into the appropriate class?

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have an `HttpResponseMessage` whose `Content` property I know to be of type `Exception`, or some subclass thereof.  Now I'm trying to deserialize that content like so:

```
var exception = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<Exception>().Result;
```

But when I do this, it throws an `AggregateException` with the message

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error parsing boolean value. Path '', line 0, position 0.

If I view the content as a string, I can see from the Json that it's of type `DivideByZeroException':

> {"ClassName":"System.DivideByZeroException","Message":"Attempted to divide by zero.","Data": ... etc...

I'd be happy to get back an `Exception` object - but does `ReadAsAsync<>` not support deserializing an object into its base class type?  If not, then what's the best way to detect what type of object I should be creating?

Comment: Check if this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738031/deserializing-json-using-json-net-with-dynamic-data

Comment: @Barnstokkr yes, I just came to the same conclusion independently, to use dynamic type.  Funnily enough, this does not solve the `ReadAsAsync<>` error; I worked around it by using the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` method instead.  Feel free to post this as an answer, anyway.  Thanks!