# Youtube Data API v3 with C#

Tags: c#, api, youtube

Here's my question:

So when you go to 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?id=PLEylltUN0Ao6PvGUOJuVOAh6sSQvwoZQ3&key=AIzaSyBr7_g-xlBCBR6Mxk_2P0GRWeM5b_aJ5uM&part=snippet

You get a lot of information but I only want one thing and that is:

at thumbnails then default and then url so how do I do that?

To make it more clear:

```
"thumbnails": {
 "default": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iilXL9y2HtE/default.jpg",
  "width": 120,
  "height": 90
 },
 "medium": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iilXL9y2HtE/mqdefault.jpg",
  "width": 320,
  "height": 180
 },
 "high": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iilXL9y2HtE/hqdefault.jpg",
  "width": 480,
  "height": 360
 },
 "standard": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iilXL9y2HtE/sddefault.jpg",
  "width": 640,
  "height": 480
 },
 "maxres": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iilXL9y2HtE/maxresdefault.jpg",
  "width": 1280,
  "height": 720
 }
},
```

And then

```
     "default": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iilXL9y2HtE/default.jpg",
  "width": 120,
  "height": 90
 },
```

And then

```
"url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iilXL9y2HtE/default.jpg",
```

I want to return that url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iilXL9y2HtE/default.jpg

I'm coding in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look on StackOverflow for an answer to your question and found these related questions, which may be helpful for you.

[Deserializing JSON using JSon.NET with dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738031/deserializing-json-using-json-net-with-dynamic-data)

[How to get a json string from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566942/how-to-get-a-json-string-from-url)

The first link describes how to achieve this using either SimpleJSON or Json.NET (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). The second link describes how to download the JSON you want to parse in C#.

In your case, you would have to change

```
string title = json.query.pages["6695"].title;
```

to something like

```
string url = json["items"][0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["default"]["url"];
```

in order to get the required url (You don't need to bother with the foreach statement). Also, "text" in the line

```
dynamic json = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject(text)
```

would have to be replaced with the downloaded JSON (see the second link).

Comment: You're getting closer! But json.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.high.url is invalid i get this as error: 
There is no definition for "items". I guess that means json.items[0]

Comment: Sorry - I've figured it out and changed my answer accordingly.